# Get token from a tab seperated string in python

Tags: python, string

I am new to python and I need to know how to split a string so that I can append the required tokens from the splitted string.

For example, say

```
a = "ALU02021543    Build   ISR52   [10G DPoE]Upstream traffic priority is not accurate and scheduler is mussy in one or different ONUs"
```

I need to split this string and append "`ALU02021543 and [10G DPoE]......`" The string is tab delimited. I tried the `.split()` function, but it returns a string that has this entire string at `0th` index. I don't know how to proceed with this?

Comment: Do you mean that your string is `"ALU02021543\tBuild ISR52\t[10G DPoE]\t Upstram..."`

Comment: can you add a complete desire output?

Comment: @Kasra "ALU02021543 [10G DPoE]Upstream traffic priority is not accurate and scheduler is mussy in one or different ONUs"   -- Desired output.

Comment: @gboffi Yes."ALU02021543\tBuild\tISR52\t[10G DPoE]\t Upstram..."

Comment: @WarriorPrince What's your expected output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj    ALU02021543 [10G DPoE]Upstream traffic priority is not accurate and scheduler is mussy in one or different ONUs

Comment: added an answer. I think this is what you looking for.

Comment: @WarriorPrince Is it possible that the variable `a` in your code snippet comes from processing a TSV file?  In that case there are a number of idioms that you may want to know, starting from the `csv` module and maybe  progressing, if your use case is complex enough to warrant its generality vs learning curve, to the `pandas` module (ask google or search SO for details). Ciao from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can `split` the your string then add the first entry with 3th to end :

```
>>> s=a.split()

>>> s[0]+' '+' '.join(s[3:])
'ALU02021543 [10G DPoE]Upstream traffic priority is not accurate and scheduler is mussy in one or different ONUs'
```

Comment: Thanks @Kasra but i need space between ALU02021543 and [10GDPoE] and after each element that comes after it.

Answer (score 0):

An answer closer to the OP question is

```
a = "ALU02021543\tBuild\tISR52\t[10G DPoE]\tUpstram traffic priority is not accurate and scheduler is mussy in one or different ONUs"
t = a.split("\t")
a_new = " ".join(t[:1]+t[3:])
print a_new
# ALU02021543 [10G DPoE] Upstram traffic priority is not accurate and scheduler is mussy in one or different ONUs
```

while something slightly more general could be written in terms of

```
strings = do(all,the,required,stuff)
for s in strings:
    # do stuff with t_list[0], t_list_[2], etc
    t_list = s.split("\t")
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the part you don't want through `re.sub`

```
>>> a = "ALU02021543    Build   ISR52   [10G DPoE]Upstream traffic priority is not accurate and scheduler is mussy in one or different ONUs"
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\t\w+\t\w+\t', r' ', a)
'ALU02021543 [10G DPoE]Upstream traffic priority is not accurate and scheduler is mussy in one or different ONUs'
```